# conditional shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I want to use a shortcode (`[ex]...[/ex]`) within the title of a post in order to style the text in a certain way (`<h1>part of <span class="ex">title</span></h1>`).

Thanks to `add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );`, it works perfectly with `the_title`.

But now, `single_post_title` which I use for `<title>` contains the shortcode as plain text `<title>part of [ex]title[/ex]</title>`. With `add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'do_shortcode' );`, the title becomes `<title>part of <span class="ex">title</span></title>`.

Is there a way to make shortcodes conditional: if it's resolved within `the_title` do this, within `single_post_title` do that?

Comment: You may be able to use [`current_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_filter/) to check if you're in `single_post_title ` and return the unformatted version.

Comment: there are a lot of places that use the title, and also don't support shortcodes or HTML tags, e.g. these shortcodes are going to be piped into twitter linkedin and facebook. Would it not make more sense to ask how to style titles in content and use shortcodes as an example instead of asking how to fix what you've already built? aka the X Y Problem fallacy? Shortcodes are not the only way to apply styling to portions of a title, there are better solutions

Comment: Thank you @Howdy_McGee, this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @Howdy_McGee! [`current_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_filter/) is exactly what I've been looking for. Here is what I did:

```
function french_example( $atts , $content = null ) {
        $currentFilter = current_filter();
    if ($currentFilter == the_content) {
      return '<span class="ex" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span>';  
    }
    elseif ($currentFilter == the_title) {
      return '<span class="ex" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span>';  
    }
    else {
      return do_shortcode($content);
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'ex', 'french_example' );
```